# Cycles Toon shader size effects diffuse direct value

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

Here are three monkeys lit by the same sun lamp. They have only a Toon Diffuse shader set to color of 0.2 value, and size of 0.8, 0.5, and 0.2 respectively. But it can clearly be seen that their lit areas are displaying very different colors. When rendered, the difference shows up in the Diffuse Direct pass.

[image]

Does anyone know why this works this way, and what is going on mathematically? I want to make an adjustment to the color going into the shader based on the size to compensate for this and bring them all back to the same level of brightness in their lit area. Is it intended for the Toon shader to behave this way? Is this a bug?

Comment: Now you've had a really good answer, I feel more free to ask.. wouldn't EEVEE and Shader to RGB, manipulated, serve you better for NPR effects?

Comment: @RobinBetts Some of them. It has a lot more control. But it isn't a proper toon shader since you are ramping the light. So changing light intensity changes the size of your shaded area, which a Cycles toon doesn't. There's strong points to both for different styles right now. Once Eevee gets a real toon shader (hopefully) then it'll be different.

Comment: Ahhh.. I see. Maybe that also goes some way to explaining the way the Cycles shader  is implemented.. but you (I) would have thought they could have written @lemon's normalization in.. at least as an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the code currently [here](https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/08005802ccb70c31e9ce5fcfe6551dc7354d3c6b/intern/cycles/kernel/closure/bsdf_toon.h#L116), and the `sample_uniform_cone` currently [here](https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/07b223a8730e37b7d8f013283ff051e493788fb8/intern/cycles/kernel/kernel_montecarlo.h#L85), without smoothing the resulting diffuse intensity depends on the size of the toon shader node.

So we can compensate this value to invert the calculation:

The size is multiplied by pi/2 (so this is relative to half cone angle).

Then take 1 minus the cosinus of the previous result.

Then divide pi/2 by the previous result.

Last, multiply the intensity value by it.

As this last step is multiplication factor in the shader code, we need to divide by it in the nodes. This is done by this node group:

[image]

The result is not exactly perfect (should be some rounding or an error by me). But we obtain this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So basically the *size* indicated(set) the max angle that the shader could reflect light, and the other area shared the same calculation of color (which is **average**)?

Comment: @Hikariztw, it seems to be. But there is other values taken into account and provided to the function: randu and randv. And don't know their calculation (have a look at the code).

Comment: That's weird... can't think of a reason to  calculate it this way ...

Comment: @RobinBetts weird? It is as it is in the code... for some reason the intensity relies on the diffuse surface. I don't know why though.

Comment: Oops, I meant them, not you. Great answer.

Comment: @RobinBetts, will try to find a way to ask (maybe Brecht) and report here if I've an answer.

Comment: @RobinBetts I thought they might want a more realistic color *(yeah, in a toon shader...)* than directly assign an user input color on it. So calculating an average intensity over that area make sense for me

Comment: Great answer! I'm making an Eevee shader group that I want to be equivalent to the Cycles toon. I've got it covering the same area, but if i've adjusted a color to work with the Cycles shader, then it ends up being too light or dark on the eevee version. So i can use this to either compensate for the cycles, or do the same change to the color in the eevee version.

Comment: @lemon Testing it out, it seems to be darkening the colors quite a bit. On a white object with enough light to look white with regular diffuse, the toon diffuse ends up coming out at .35 value. It is consistently that regardless of the size though. But it ought to be white at any size! Any idea why this is or how to fix?

Comment: @Drudge, hard to see there are many factors (lights, color management). Do you have some sample file for calibration (including eventually the Eevee shader)?

Comment: For information, suggested on blender-coders chat (by Jeroen Bakker): toon shader respects conservation of energy in Cycles and that may be why the colors are different depending on the size (@RobinBetts)

Comment: @lemon OK. Rooted in the fundamental conflict between the goals of  PBR and NPR. On that basis,  a purist would say there shouldn't _be_ a toon shader in Cycles, I guess..

Comment: @lemon The EV shader will need to be for another topic. It looks like multiplying the value by 3 before combining the HSV makes the toon value match the brightest value on a regular diffuse. This holds up with just a single sun lamp at different strengths. But once you add world lighting, the toon gets too bright. So there's more to it. Here's my test file. It's just a comp of regular diffuse and toon with the group from your answer and the multiply: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6540/

Comment: @Drudge, no idea about this 3 value. don't see it in the code. Though, the linked code is called by something and I don't know where. Maybe a way can be adding this adjustment value as node group entry in the node group that makes the calculation, for flexibility (but 3 is really big for something supposed to be between 0 and 1, so that's strange)..

Comment: @lemon It's just a value I found that happened to look right when using only a sun lamp. There's got to be some proper amount to adjust by to have the toon shader achieve the proper amount of brightness in different lighting setups.

Comment: @Drudge, Thanks for the bounty. I agree there should be some calculation to find the value, but really don't know how. I think energy conservation law is the key, but this is handle externally to the shader (we for instance don't know the incoming light intensity).

Comment: @lemon sounds like a dead end for now then. i'm not really sure where else we could go from here? Thanks for what you were able to figure out.